# How to display multiple colums from a SQL Connection in a listbox? (ASP.Net Web Application on VS)

Tags: sql, asp.net, listbox, connection, multiple-columns

I am trying to get the values of data from four different columns of an SQL table to display in my list-box so that the format is "value1, value2, value3, value4".  I have my SQL connection control set up with two joins that I have tested in SSMS and pulls the current data.  So far I can only get one column of data to display at a time, and I am wondering what the best method would be to display all four values separated by commas.[my screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Tv2E.png)

I have tried making variables to attach each value with a .SelectedValue, but this did not alter the appearance of the list-box whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

First, always paste in your code (a screen shot means I can't grab your code - and it not pracital to re-type or test your code "as is".

However, the main issue/problem with a listbox is they really only are designed to display one column (and a hidden database row PK used for selecting the options).

As a result, it makes more sense to use a different control since listbox only displays ONE column from the database.

So, I could fill a listbox with hotel names, allow multiple selections and have the code spit out a list of "pk id" for the selecting.

So, say this markup:

```
        <h2>Select Hotels</h2>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName" Width="192px" Height="180px" 
            SelectionMode="Multiple" >
        </asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShowSel" runat="server" 
            Text="Show Selections" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdShowSel_Click" />
```

Note VERY close in above, the 2 setting for the listbox (datavalue = hidden database PK value, and DataTextField = display column).

so, while I am feeding the listbox many columns, it can only display one column (text), and also return the hidden database PK value of id (value).

So, code behind can be this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                ListBox1.DataSource = rstData;
                ListBox1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void cmdShowSel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListItem OneRow in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (OneRow.Selected)
            {
                Debug.Print($"Database PK = {OneRow.Value} Text = {OneRow.Text}");
            }
        }
    }
```

So, we run this

hold down ctrl-key and click for multiple selectons.

[image]

And now when I click the button, I get this output to the debug/immediate window:

output:

```
Database PK = 16 Text = Batman's Cave
Database PK = 5 Text = Inns of Banff
Database PK = 6 Text = Swiss Village
```

However, if we want multiple columns, then better to use a listview, or even perahps a grid view.

Lets use a gridview.

So, now this markup:

And code behind, much the same, but we use a select *, and get all columns from the database.

So, this code:

```
    void LoadData()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = 
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

<h2>Select Hotels</h2>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" Width="40%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select " ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And we now see/get this:

[image]

So, as you can see, the above allows multiple columns were as a listbox does not.

The UI is also nice, since the user does not have use ctrl-click (that can be tricky for new users).

So, now our button click code is this:

```
protected void cmdShowSel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow OneRow in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkMySel = (CheckBox)OneRow.FindControl("chkSel");
        if (chkMySel.Checked)
        {
            int PK = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[OneRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
            string s = 
                $"row index click {OneRow.RowIndex} " +
                $"Data base PK = {PK} "  +
                $"Hotel name = {OneRow.Cells[1].Text}";
            Debug.Print(s);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
row index click 1 Data base PK = 5 Hotel name = Inns of Banff
row index click 7 Data base PK = 6 Hotel name = Swiss Village
```

So, a listbox is the wrong choice of a control for displaying multiple columns of data.